# Saving lists to txt file

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to save a list to a text file.

This is my code:

```
public void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("SavedLists.txt");

    tw.WriteLine(Lists.verbList);
    tw.Close();
}
```

This is what I get in the text file:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Do I have to use `ConvertAll<>`? If so, I'm not sure how to use that.

Comment: where in your code do you define `List.verbList`..?

Comment: Clearly the OP is new to Stack Overflow.  Give him a break.  No need for the downvoting, just leave helpful comments.

Comment: you could do something like this also very simple
`Lists.verbList.ForEach(delegate(string strListContents)
  {
           tw.WriteLine(strListContents);
  });`

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Assuming your Generic List is of type String:

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("SavedList.txt");

foreach (String s in Lists.verbList)
   tw.WriteLine(s);

tw.Close();
```

Alternatively, with the using keyword:

```
using(TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("SavedList.txt"))
{
   foreach (String s in Lists.verbList)
      tw.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: `Bhushan` the negative 1 vote is not appropriate here what if the OP does not want to use the Using ? +3 this is a good answer

Comment: @BhushanFirake that's bad reasoning. 1) the corrected sample matches the asker's style. 2) The object is closed correctly. You may not like the style, but it's perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks! I'm doing summer school of code and this helped me with my homework!

Answer (score 133):

No need to use StreamWriter since Framework 4:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("SavedLists.txt", Lists.verbList);
```

Answer (score 8):

@Jon's answer is great and will get you where you need to go. So why is your code printing out what it is. The answer: You're not writing out the contents of your list, but the String representation of *your list itself*, by an implicit call to Lists.verbList.ToString(). [Object.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) defines the default behavior you're seeing here.